# NGINX + PHP7 + FastCGI Not Executing PHP Files and Downloading PHP file to client

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, fastcgi

The title says it all... follows are my config files.

There have to be many others looking for an updated solution to the FastCGI configuration woes.

Merci!

nginx -t

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
```

curl -i http://ipaddress

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.10.2
Date: Tue, 28 Mar 2017 21:18:20 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 1780
Last-Modified: Thu, 15 Dec 2016 15:20:08 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
ETag: "5852b4a8-6f4"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

nginx/php-fpm generated no errors in logs

nginx access log generated the following.

```
192.88.135.5 - - [28/Mar/2017:13:18:38 -0400] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 1780 "-""Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36 OPR/43.0.2442.1144"
```

files in .sock path directory

```
-rw-r--r--. 1 root  root  5 Mar 28 18:13 php-fpm.pid
srw-rw----. 1 nginx nginx 0 Mar 28 18:13 website.com.sock
```

nginx version: nginx/1.10.2
PHP 7.0.16 (fpm-fcgi) (built: Feb 18 2017 10:26:54)

nginx.conf

```
user  nginx nginx;
worker_processes  4;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  notice;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log  info;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
     keepalive_timeout  65;

    upstream php {
    server unix:/var/run/php-fpm/website.com.sock;
    }

    server {
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-available/*.conf;
    }
}
```

default.conf

```
include /etc/nginx/security;
#expires max;

#Uploads configuration
client_max_body_size 32m;
```

site-available/site.conf

```
listen [::]:80;
server_name *.website.com;
root /some/directory/website/;

access_log  /var/log/nginx/www.access.log;
error_log  /var/log/nginx/www.error.log notice;

#fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
include fastcgi_params;

#Index targets
index index.php index.html index.htm;

location / {

    # redirect admin/auth
    #rewrite ^/(admin|auth)(.*) https://$host$request_uri?;

    # try_files $uri =404;
    # #fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

}

# if the file being requested ends in ".php", it's something
#    that PHP-FPM should process, so hand it to upstream server

location ~ \.php$ {
    fastcgi_pass php;
}
```

php-fpm/www.conf

```
; Start a new pool named 'www'.
[www]

ping./var/run/php-fpm/website.com.sock = /ping
listen = /var/run/php-fpm/website.com.sock;
pm = dynamic
pm.status_/var/run/php-fpm/website.com.sock = /status

user = nginx
group = nginx

listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0666

pm.max_children = 5
pm.start_servers = 2
pm.min_spare_servers = 1
pm.max_spare_servers = 3
```

fastcgi.conf

```
fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME    $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

#  To use NGINX + Virtual Host + PHP you should ommit the SCRIPT_NAME     variable in order for 
#   PHP to choose the correct DOCUMENT_ROOT.
#fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
#

fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: please try to write a minimal complete and verifible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .Pasting a lot of code doesnt help very much.

Comment: Thanks for your interest.  I have removed anything i consider to be unrelated (ex. gzip, comments)

Comment: if you ask your question on serverfault.com you may get more help

Comment: try https://github.com/indra1/nginx_config_examples/blob/master/nginx_fastcgi_example

Comment: i have tried that configuration among many iterations.  From what I can tell, it looks like FastCGI is not picking up the file and, if so, that could be because the fastcgi_script_name is not configured correctly.  I will append my fastcgi.conf to the question; it is small.

Comment: do i need to replace $document_root/$fastcgo_script_name; with path/filefastcgi.conf?

Comment: What is in the access log, the error log and the output of `nginx -T`?

Comment: nginx -t added at top